# How to call a function inside a promise with reduce function in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, reduce

Here is my array

```
arr = [2,3,4]
```

here is my functions

```
function functionMultpily(p1, p2) {
  return( p1 * p2);  
}

function functionADD(p1, p2) {
  return( p1 + p2);  
}
```

I need to use this functions in a promise such that it should complete one after another by taking the values from arr by using Reduce function.

Comment: It’s not clear what you’re asking. There’s nothing async here.

Comment: the functions I wrote are sample and in real time the functions are async, I just need to call those functions inside a promise such a way it should execute one after another

Comment: So after using the functions, what is your expected result?

Answer (score 3):

First make sure your functions return promises, for instance by returning `Promise.resolve(a*b)` instead of `a*b`.

Then apply `reduce` on the array of values, where in each iteration you accumulate (chain) one promise to the next. There second argument of `reduce` (initial value) is not used, so the first callback that `reduce` makes is with the first and second array value as arguments. As we want the accumulator to be a promise, and at the start it clearly isn't, apply `Promise.resolve` to the accumulator:

```js
function multiply(a, b) {
  let c = a * b;
  console.log(a + " * " + b + " = " + c);
  return Promise.resolve(c);
}

function add(a, b) {
  let c = a + b;
  console.log(a + " + " + b + " = " + c);
  return Promise.resolve(c);
}

let arr = [2,3,4];
let functions = [multiply, add];

arr.reduce((acc, b, i) => Promise.resolve(acc).then(a => functions[i-1](a, b)))
   .then(console.log);
```

The accumulator is from then on always a promise that resolves to an (intermediate) result (like a product or sum). 
In the `reduce` callback, you chain a `then` on that promised value. Once resolved, execute the desired function (`add` or `multiply`) passing it both the resolved value and the next value from the array. The result of `then()` is again a promise, which will be the accumulator value in the next iteration.

Finally, print out the reduced value that `reduce` will promise.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Promise.resolve()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve) along with [`Promise.prototype.then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) as follows:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

const sleep = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

const add = (a, b) => sleep(500).then(() => a + b);
const multiply = (a, b) => sleep(500).then(() => a * b);

arr
  .reduce((p, x) => p.then((y) => add(x, y)), Promise.resolve(0))
  .then(sum => console.log(sum));

arr
  .reduce((p, x) => p.then((y) => multiply(x, y)), Promise.resolve(1))
  .then(product => console.log(product));
```

Answer (score -2):

this is the way to call function one after other.

```
Promise.series([
    new Promise(function functionMultpily(p1, p2) {
  resolve( p1 * p2);  
}),
    new Promise(function functionADD(p1, p2) {
  resolve( p1 + p2);  
})
    ]).then(function(val){
// do any further computation here.
        console.log(val);
    }).catch(function(e){
        console.error(e.stack);
    });
```

Comment: `new Promise(function functionMultpily(p1, p2) {
  resolve( p1 * p2);  
})` does not make any sense. `p1` is `resolve` and `p2` is `reject` and your `resolve` is not defined anywhere.

Comment: Also, `series` is not a method in standard EcmaScript (yet). Moreover, there is nothing to "serialise" when you *immediately* execute `new Promise`. Where did you get that *"this is the way"*?